# Can Whatsapp be MAC spoofed if the victim's device isn't on the same local network as the hacker's device?

Tags: network, ip-spoofing, mac-address, whatsapp, mac-spoofing

I realize that MAC addresses are only used to tell different devices apart **if they are on the same local network.** So, what if they're not? Is MAC spoofing in Whatsapp still possible? Even if the perpetrator obtained the confirmation code from my phone, would it be possible, to unverify my account in the process?

And what if they also tried spoofing the IP address? Would it eventually unverify the account on one of the devices once the IP address on either one of them changed and Whatsapp noticed there were two verified instances of one account at the same time?

Comment: I believe you might be misunderstanding the role MAC addresses play and how it might relate to a application  such as WhatsApp. WhatsApp does not verify users by MAC address, but by “higher” layers such as username and password. Taking a look at TCP/IP model might help

Comment: ... I have no idea what you're trying to ask. whatsapp is based on the [signal protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_Protocol) which I thought derived its security from public-key cryptography and not IPs or MAC addresses. Can you provide some background links to explain how you arrived at this conclusion?

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea where you got your information, but let's start at the very beginning citing reputable sources as we go.

[This youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k-vm46ldvhI) shows the process for enrolling a new device in WhatsApp. Since WhatsApp is built on the same cryptography as the Signal app -- called the Signal Protocol ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WhatsApp#End-to-end_encryption)), let's assume they do the same stuff inside (Signal is open source while WhatsApp is owned by Facebook, so easier to know what's going on in Signal).

Enrollment Steps:

1. Provide your mobile phone number.
2. The server sends you an SMS with a one-time activation code.
3. The device creates a cryptographic public key.
4. The server registers this public key against your phone number in a big database.

You are now enrolled. When your friend wants to send you an encrypted message, they ask the server for the public key(s) registered to your phone number, and they can start encrypting for you.

I've never used WhatsApp, but Signal lets you link as many devices as you want to your phone number. But there is a menu to unlink devices.

---

Nowhere in there does it use your IP or MAC addresses, so whichever friend told you that is probably not a reliable source for tech info.

It does however assume that you are the only person who can receive SMSes at your phone number, so if you lose your SIM card, or are paranoid about nation-states, then it's possible for someone to register a second device under your phone number, and then (if it works the same as Signal) unlink your first device. So don't lose your SIM card.

Comment: So, from what I understand, Whatsapp uses your mobile phone number and the confirmation code they send you via SMS as some sort of "login details", right? Because they suspect only you, the owner of the phone number, can receive the SMS verification code. That's reasonable. However, if Whatsapp doesn't allow the account to be logged in on more than one device at a time, does that mean that my account on my device would instantly become unverified (unavailable) the same moment they verified it on their phone? This would mean that having two verified accounts at a time should be impossible.

Comment: To add to this, how does exactly Signal know how many devices are linked to your account? It surely must use something to tell devices apart, otherwise you wouldn't be able to unlink them.

Comment: I've never used WhatsApp, so I'm going off my experience with Signal. You don't really "log in" -- there's no username or password. Instead, each device registers a cryptographic public key with the main WhatsApp / Signal sever. (think of this like a phone book of signal "email addresses" registered to your phone number). There is no problem registering multiple public keys (ie multiple devices) for one phone number. When someone wants to encrypt for you, they ask the server for all your public keys and encrypt a copy of the message for each one.

Comment: Unlinking a device is simple: you just remove that public key from the list associated with your phone number on the server. The next time someone sends you a message, they will no longer encrypt a copy for that public key / device. That device will see that there are new massages, but won't be able to decrypt them. (this is simplified, I'm sure the actual signal protocol has more moving pieces, but that's the part relevant to your question)

Comment: "There is no problem registering multiple public keys (ie multiple devices) for one phone number." But Whatsapp clearly states that this is in fact not possible. Source: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/21009863/?category=5245245 Perhaps, if they tried to register a public key for their device, my key would be removed from the database, i.e. the key I have on my phone wouldn't match the key they store on their server and I would be notified that my account on my device is unverified, while theirs would become verified in the proccess.

Comment: If you watch this video at about 4:21 you can see this in action when this person enters the victim's phone number and their newly received verification code (which can be received if you, say, steal someones phone). Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fDJ-88e_06A
What bugs me is how people claim it is possible to spoof (clone) a person's Whatsapp account by changing their MAC address to the victim's one and just "logging in" with the verification code as one normally would.  If MAC address doesn't play any role in identifying your account then this should be just about impossible to do.

Comment: For an example, a detailed instruction is given https://www.hackthis.co.uk/forum/hacking-security/tutorials-articles/27364-mac-spoofing-for-whatsapp-hacking?page=1 here, https://www.quora.com/Does-the-changing-of-a-Mac-address-work-for-hacking-WhatsApp-If-so-how-is-the-process-done here and https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-hack-someones-WhatsApp-account-by-rooting-our-Mac-address-as-same-as-the-culprits-Mac-address here... Any idea what's going on? Is it all just an elaborate scam to get people to download their apps, or an actual threat to your Whatsapp account's security?

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of links. I'll look tomorrow. Certainly you can register multiple devices in Signal, maybe Whatsapp is different? I'll look tomorrow.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth I've never used either Signal or WhatsApp, but I could imagine them only holding one key at a time, since -- going by your first comment -- to support more they'd have to encrypt each message multiple times and send all variants to each device.

Comment: @TripeHound The Signal Protocol certainly does that, which is a required component of the encrypted group chat functionality.

Comment: Surely in a group chat a sender's message is encrypted for each group participant individually. If it wasn't, end-to-end encrypted group chats would be impossible to acheive. The question that arises is whether one account can have multiple public keys linked to it at the same time. This would mean that the sender would encrypt the same message multiple times for the same recipient, and that would contradict the Whatsapp's claim that it can only be verified with one number for one device (at the time).

Comment: Say you bought a new phone and had to move your Whatsapp account to it. You would put your SIM card in it, download a Whatsapp app, enter in your phone number and receive an SMS with your new verification code. The moment you typed in the verification code and pressed enter, you've generated a completely new public key for your account, and the old one is now obsolete. You now have full access to your Whatsapp account on the new device, and you cannot access it on your old device anymore.

Comment: Let's take a different approach. What if someone were able to generate, on their device, the very same public key that is already stored in the database for my device? Whatsapp public keys are generated locally, i.e. on the device. Would that fool Whatsapp into thinking that my account was active on only one device? What does Whatsapp use to generate a new public key, say, when you change your device? It must use something on the phone, could it be the MAC address? That would be practical for them, but also a huge security hole. You don't even need access to the device to find out its MAC.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth You'd help me a lot if you take a look on those links I posted here in the comments yesterday and gave me your objective opinion. This "MAC spoof" thing is a real mystery for me and I would love more than anything to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: @JeanDieu I've been crazy busy the past few days (sorry). In Signal you certainly can register more than one device per phone number -- I currently have Signal open on both my phone and my laptop and whenever someone sends me a message, it goes to both. Note that when I add a new device, it can only see messages from then onwards, it doesn't have any access to past messages. If WhatsApp is making the claim _"Whatsapp's claim that it can only be verified with one number for one device (at the time)"_, then my assumption that they behave the same is clearly wrong.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth No problem man. Thank you for your time. I've asked another question here regarding my issue, only this time I pinpointed my exact concerns as I've learned something from you, which was indeed quite helpful. The link to my new more in-depth question is here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/192052/can-a-whatsapp-account-be-spoofed